# Image send to email but not attachament, image inputed image from site

Tags: image, email

I have a contact form and I have some images for every field. When I send email I want to have to email the image of every field, but this show me just link. Here is the code for image:

```
<td rowspan="8" width="44%" style="padding-right: 270px;"><img src="../images/ferestre-fixe/thumb_150_120_03-2.jpg" style="border: 0px none; float: right;" title=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="a3cmgif" id="a3cmgif" value="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];?>/images/ferestre-fixe/thumb_150_120_03-2.jpg" readonly/>
</td>
```

OK, we have `<input type="hidden" name="a3cmgif" id="a3cmgif" value="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];?>/images/ferestre-fixe/thumb_150_120_03-2.jpg" readonly/>`, but I got to mail http://www.example.com/images/ferestre-fixe/thumb_150_120_03-2.jpg

I want to receive to mail directly image. I tried with img src but this send me to mail the code comment.